# R error while using OR

Tags: r

In a dataframe poll, statement 1 works but statement 2 does not. Any advise as why this is happening ? Error which is coming wrong.

**Statement 1:**

```
test = subset(poll, Internet.Use=="1" | Smartphone == "1")
```

**Statement 2 :**

```
 limited = subset(po11, Internet.Use=="1" | Smartphone == "1")
```

> Error in subset(po11, Internet.Use == "1" | Smartphone == "1") :
>   object 'po11' not found

Comment: wild guess: `po11` doesn't exist in your workspace

Answer (score 0):

In your second statement you are writing `po11` (with two digits "1" instead of two characters "l").
Therefore R can´t find this object, because it doesn´t exist.